# Fragment doesn't save current item of ViewPager when it's inside other fragment after screen rotation

Tags: android, android-viewpager, fragment

I have one problem. Problem saving current item of ViewPager when it's inside other fragment after rotating screen. I have made demo project.

https://docs.google.com/file/d/0BxIpMptddSJsWHJTYS1tUXlPVTQ/edit?usp=sharing&pli=1

Comment: I have fixed this problem but I don't know right this or not. if (getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentById(android.R.id.content) == null) {
   FragmentTransaction jobSearchTranscaction = this
     .getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
   VPFragment vp = new VPFragment();
   jobSearchTranscaction.replace(android.R.id.content, vp);
   jobSearchTranscaction.commit();
  }

Comment: Hi. Clicked the "Answer Your Own Question" link below and put your answer there, and use appropriate formatting so it can be readable for others. Thanks!